# Mediation analysis and no difference in explanatory variable's point estimate

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mediation

I am attempting to perform mediation analysis to explain variable $y$
as a function of $x$, $z_{1}.$ and $z_{2}$. $x$ is the variable
of interest, while $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ are the mediating variables.
I run the following regression:
$$
y=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x+\epsilon
$$
and I obtain an estimate of $\beta,$$\hat{\beta}.$ I then run another
regression, augmenting the original regression with the variables
$z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$
$$
y=\gamma_{0}+\gamma_{1}x+\gamma_{2}z+\gamma_{3}z_{2}+v
$$
The second regression delivers significant point estimates on $z_{1},$
and $z_{2}$ , namely $\hat{\gamma}_{1}$ and $\hat{\gamma}_{2}$
but also a value of $\hat{\gamma}_{1}$ which is very close to $\hat{\beta}_{1}.$
Specifically, I am unable to reject the null that:
$$
H_{0}:\hat{\gamma}_{1}-\hat{\beta_{1}}=0
$$
Is it correct to interpret, therefore, that there is no mediating
effect of $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ on $x?$ Could it be that the mediation
effect of $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ oppose each other? It is indeed suprising,
because as long as, for example, $corr\left(x,z_{1}\right)$ is not
0, and $z_{1}$ is significant, it is strange that the point estimate
on $x$ does not change. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Should it perhaps read $y=\gamma_{0}+\gamma_{\color{red}{1}}x+\gamma_{\color{red}{2}}z_{1}+\gamma_{3}z_{2}+v$ instead of $y=\gamma_{0}+\gamma_{2}x+\gamma_{1}z+\gamma_{3}z_{2}+v$ and ...significant point estimates on $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$, namely $\hat\gamma_{\color{red}{2}}$ and $\hat\gamma_{\color{red}{3}}$ instead of ...  namely $\hat\gamma_1$ and $\hat\gamma_2$ ?

Comment: Yes @Ute . I have fixed the typo.

Comment: I think you are right that it could mean that $z_1$ and $z_2$ have opposite effects. The answer depends on how you define "no mediating effect".